# Entry and Picker in collection view header in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, picker, collectionview

I have used entry and Picker in collection view header and it works fine in android.But in ios when I click on the entry or picker the page is getting down.Is there anyway to resolve this!?

I have issue similar to https://gitub.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9879#issuecomment-609627755

Comment: Please show us a minimal code sample that reproduces the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Add video or code so we can identify what's the issue.